# Why is "& ;" invalid syntax?

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax

I am trying to run a for loop on the terminal where I want to send each iteration to background process so that all of them run simultaneously.

Following is the command running one by one

```
for i in *.sra; do fastq-dump --split-files $i ; done  # ";" only
```

I have highlighted the semicolon.

To run simultaneously this works

```
for i in *.sra; do fastq-dump --split-files $i & done  # "&" only
```

But this gives an error

```
for i in *.sra; do fastq-dump --split-files $i & ; done  # "& ;"
```

It would be nice if some one explains what is going on here. I know this should be written in a shell script way with proper indentation, but some times I only have this command to run.

Comment: learn to use http://shellcheck.net before posting your Q. The error flagged was "SC1045: It's not 'foo &; bar', just 'foo & bar'."` . Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` and `;` both terminate the command that precedes them.

You can't write `& ;` any more than you could write `; ;` or `& &`, because the language only allows a command to be terminated once (and doesn't permit a zero-word list as a command).

---

Thus: `for i in *.src; do fastq-dump --split-files "$i" & done` is perfectly correct as-is, and does not require an additional `;`.

Comment: So & at the end of my command is enough?? Also can you see the highlighted bold semicolon in my question. For some reason it is not bold althoguh I selected B option

Comment: You can't bold things inside code blocks. And yes, just `&` is enough.